# Phase transition in traffic jam: some reference on it for statistical physics students?

Tags: resource-recommendations, phase-transition

I would like to know if there are good resources about the physical point of view of traffic jam, in link with the phases transition.

Indeed, everything that I have found is either too short (just a paper, or a small presentation), either too long (a full book that would take a really long time to be understood).

In fact I am looking for a class that could be taught at university to physics students that don't know anything about traffic jam theory at first (but that knows statistical physics). I would like to be able to explain the global theory of it after 2 days of work on the topic for example (to give an idea). To give another Idea, something like 20-30 pages long would be nice (it can be longer of course but I want to get the global idea in 20-30 pages).

Remark : it is for a presentation I have to do in statistical physics, and I found this subject very interesting and some original, but as I said everything I found is either really too short to understand what is happening, or really too long.

Comment: -1 Did you try googling your title?  [Statistical physics of traffic flow](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437100002740)   is 20 pages, and [The physics of traffic jams](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.205.6595&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which is 55 pages.

Comment: @sammygerbil At this rate, one may say the same of at least 10% of the questions on this site (those for which a simple internet search or browsing through any standard book would immediately yield an answer). I am not opposed (on the contrary) to downvoting, or even closing, all such questions but then it should be applied uniformly.

Comment: @sammygerbil Google is a mindless automaton.  It can help dig out references that have the key words in them, and can even help you find ones within a certain page length range, but are those references any good?  Are they at the appropriate level for the OP's needs?  IMO it's absolutely appropriate to consult the *human* community for answers to such questions.  Google is pretty good as an archive of *information*, but is not very good at providing *knowledge* such as the OP was seeking.

Answer (score 3):

The classic reference, which you probably already know, is I. Prigogine and R. Herman, *Kinetic Theory of Vehicular Traffic*, New York: American Elsevier (1971), but that may be too long/detailed for your purposes.  A recent review and critique of their approach that might be more accessible is M. L. L. Iannini and R. Dickman, "Kinetic Theory of Vehicular Traffic," AJP **84**, 135 (2016).  They mention traffic jams in analogy with Bose-Einstein condensation.  If that's too limited you can probably follow up with some of the references in it.
-- pwf